# Assuming Role and calling Lambda from inside EKS Pod

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, clojure, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

I have an application running in a pod on EKS, and would like for it to call a Lambda function, and am struggling with permissions and security.

What I'd like to do is use STS to assume my Lambda Invocation role (which has the `AWSLambda_FullAccess` managed policy applied to it), and then run the Lambda.

In EKS, my pod is running under a default service account, and as such, I believe the role that it has assigned to it is my EKS node role (which has `AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy` and `AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly` applied per [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-node-role.html)).

**On the EKS Node role, I have the following trust relationship configured:**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<my-account-number>:role/<lambda-invoker-role-name>"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

**On my Lambda Invoker role, I have the following the following trust relationships configured:**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [

    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<my-account-number>:role/<my-eks-worker-node-role-name>"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {}
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
```

When, in my app (running in the EKS pod), I attempt to use STS to assume my lambda invoker role, it seems to work -- I can print the credentials and actually get an `AccessKeyId`, `SecretAccessKey`, `SessionToken`, and `Expiration`.

**The code that I'm running to assume the STS Role: [Based heavily on this example](https://github.com/cognitect-labs/aws-api/blob/master/examples/assume_role_example.clj)**

```clj
(defn assumed-role-credentials-provider [role-arn]
  (let [sts (aws/client {:api :sts})
        _ (println "defining cred provider")]
    (credentials/cached-credentials-with-auto-refresh
     (reify credentials/CredentialsProvider
       (fetch [_]
         (let [_ (println "Trying to assume role")
               {:keys [Credentials] :as creds}
               (aws/invoke sts
                           {:op      :AssumeRole
                            :request {:RoleArn         role-arn
                                      :RoleSessionName (str (gensym "example-session-"))}})]
           (if Credentials
             (do 
               (println Credentials)
               {:aws/access-key-id     (:AccessKeyId creds)
                :aws/secret-access-key (:SecretAccessKey creds)
                :aws/session-token     (:SessionToken creds)
                ::credentials/ttl      (credentials/calculate-ttl creds)})
             (println "Failed to assume role: " creds))))))))

(def lambda (aws/client {:api :lambda
                         :credentials-provider (assumed-role-credentials-provider "arn:aws:iam::<my-acct-number>:role/<lambda-executor-role-name>")}))

(defn aws-test []
  (let [session-name (str (gensym "example-session-"))]
    (aws/invoke lambda {:op :Invoke
                        :request {:FunctionName "clearflow-pipeline-fn-aster_ubs_zurich_transactions"
                                  ;; :RoleSessionName session-name
                                  :Payload (ch/generate-string {:start_time "2020-12-18"
                                                                :end_time "2020-12-19"})}})))
```

However, when I try to invoke my lambda, I get an error message of `The security token included in the request is invalid.`

I feel like my role assumption is working fine, however I must be missing something with running the actual lambda -- is there a configuration setting I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Your application shouldn't do anything special to assume role. EKS can handle that automatically: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts-technical-overview.html. On a side node, it's important to apply an iptables rule to your nodes to prevent pods from gaining node-level IAM access.

Comment: @jordanm definitely -- and that's definitely my end-state. I'm just in a situation right now where I need to get something fixed with minimal architecture changes until a near-term larger, system wide re-architecture happens.

Comment: In that case, I would provide the pod with access keys via a k8s secret/env var until you can establish a better system

Comment: Is using access keys preferable to using STS to assume a role?

Comment: I would personally say it's preferable to having a pod use the host node's IAM role to manually assume another. Using access keys while generally isn't best practice, does accomplish the goal of isolating permissions. If you go the other route, every pod in your cluster will have the ability to assume that role, which probably isn't desired

Comment: That makes sense.  At this point every pod likely will need access, but I certainly see the bigger picture about isolation. That said, I still feel like this setup should at least be functioning correctly, even if not following best practices.

Comment: That's true, it probably should still function in this current state. Can you show the code that does the assume role and calls the lambda API?

Comment: @jordanm I added a code example as you requested.  It's in Clojure, so apologies if that makes it more difficult.